# I'm getting a problem when I want to get my picture download link Flutter (No App Check token for request.)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am getting such an error when getting the download link of the photo I uploaded to firebase.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVq45.png)

Source:[Github](https://github.com/serhan2004/Elektron-2/blob/main/lib/ekranlar/pfotodegis.dart)

```dart
    uploadImageToFirebase() async {
    File yuklenecekDosya = _imagefile!;
    firebase_storage.Reference referansYol = firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("Profilresimleri")
        .child(user!.uid)
        .child("profilresmi.png");




    firebase_storage.UploadTask yuklemeGorevi =
        referansYol.putFile(yuklenecekDosya);
    yuklemeGorevi.then((s) {
      if (s.state.toString() == firebase_storage.TaskState.success.toString()) {
        downloadURL = referansYol.getDownloadURL().toString();
        print(referansYol.getDownloadURL().toString());
        print(referansYol.getDownloadURL().toString());
        print(referansYol.getDownloadURL().toString());
        print(referansYol.getDownloadURL().toString());
        print(referansYol.getDownloadURL().toString());
      }
    });

    //= await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
    //  .ref('Profilresimleri/${user!.uid}/profilresmi.png')
    //.getDownloadURL();
    await firestore
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .set({"profilfotolink": downloadURL}, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
```

problem

```
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 3803): uid=10148(com.example.ekinoks_elektron) FirestoreWorker identical 3 lines
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/flutter ( 3803): Instance of 'Future<String>'
I/chatty  ( 3803): uid=10148(com.example.ekinoks_elektron) 1.ui identical 3 lines
I/flutter ( 3803): Instance of 'Future<String>'
6
W/NetworkRequest( 3803): No App Check token for request.
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/kinoks_elektro( 3803): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code, Firestore's `set()` method is getting called before the uploading is done. The execution of upload should return String but its asynchronous behaviour is expecting `await` before the execution happens (that's the reason you're getting the Future logged in console). You should await for storage to upload the file.

So the final code will be:

```
uploadImageToFirebase() async {
    File yuklenecekDosya = _imagefile!;
    firebase_storage.Reference referansYol = firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("Profilresimleri")
        .child(user!.uid)
        .child("profilresmi.png");


    firebase_storage.UploadTask yuklemeGorevi =
        referansYol.putFile(yuklenecekDosya);
    await yuklemeGorevi.then((s) {
      if (s.state.toString() == firebase_storage.TaskState.success.toString()) {
        downloadURL = referansYol.getDownloadURL().toString();
        print("Download URL: $downloadURL");
      }
    });

    await firestore
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .set({"profilfotolink": downloadURL}, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
```